# How get all the values in the rows just deleted? - sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I deleted a row of my table  with the `where` clause in Python sqlite3, then how can I get all the column values of that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is impossible: [SQLite's `delete`has no `returning` clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

Do a select, then do a delete, in the same transaction.